# Cakephp Mail Project Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on Cakephp 3 project. I want my user can send mail to  multiple recipient I  am Facing problem I Cannot Insert Value of multiple checkboxes at once.PLz help me. thank you sorry for bad english.

[image]

Controller Code

[image]

```
/**
 * Add method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
 */
public function add()
{
    $this->loadModel("Users");
    $OrganizationId = $this->Auth->user(['OrganizationId']); 

    $Users = $this->Users->find('all');
    $this->set('Ulist',$Users);

    $usernamer = $this->Auth->user(['username']); 
    $senderId = $this->Auth->user(['PId']); 
    $mail = $this->Mail->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Date'] = date("Y/m/d");
        $this->request->data['Sender'] = $usernamer;
        $this->request->data['SenderId'] = $senderId;
        $this->request->data['Type'] = $senderId;
        $mail = $this->Mail->patchEntity($mail, $this->request->getData());

        if ($this->Mail->saveMany($mail)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The mail has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('The mail could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('mail'));
}
```

form code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?= $this->Form->create($mail) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Mail') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('Subject',['class' => 'form-control','type' => 'text']);
        echo $this->Form->control('Body',['class' => 'form-control']);
        echo $this->Form->control('Attachment');
    ?>
    <select id="catagory" data-child="family" class="form-control" name="Priority">
        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <div class="resume-box"> 
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></div><br><br>

        <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Users');?></legend>
<?php
foreach ($Ulist as $grades):
    /*
    if($grades->PId != 0){
        echo "<label>";
        echo $this->Form->checkbox('Mail.'.$grades['id'].'ReceptionistId[]',array('value'=>$grades['PId'],'multiple' => 'checkbox')); 
        echo $grades->username. "</label>";
    }
    */

    // output all the checkboxes at once
    echo $this->Form->checkbox('ReceptionistId',array(
        'label' => __('ReceptionistId',true),
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $grades->PId,
    )); 

    /*
    // output all the checkboxes individually
    $checked = $form->value('Tag.Tag');
    echo $form->label(__('Tags',true));
    foreach ($tags as $id=>$label) {
        echo $form->input("Tag.checkbox.$id", array(
            'label'=>$label,
            'type'=>'checkbox',
            'checked'=>(isset($checked[$id])?'checked':false),
        ));
    }
    */

endforeach;
?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</fieldset><br>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'),['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Post code not screenshots of code. What part of this isn't working? Checking the boxes? Or the saving the results? Post the template code for generating the form.

Comment: Saving the Results Code